# Internal Server Error on OSQA install using fastcgi on Hostgator

Tags: python, fastcgi

Before start, I have no Python experience or WSGI or FastCGI for that matter, but Iam trying to take a stab at installing [OSQA](http://osqa.net/) on a shared hosting account at Hostgator.

So far, what I have done is:

1. Installed markdown, and html5lib usin:

   ```
   pip install --user markdown
   ```

   This installed in `/home/user/.local/lib/python2.6/*`
2. checked out the OSQA code at /home/user/osqa
3. Replaced DB settings for OSQA install
4. Generated DB & migrated:

   ```
   python manage.py syncdb –all

   python manage.py migrate forum --fake
   ```
5. Created a directory mysite.com to which the domain mysqite.com points to
6. Created an .htaccess file inside mysite.com:

   ```
   AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi 
   Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^(media/.*)$ - [L]
   RewriteRule ^(adminmedia/.*)$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(osqa.fcgi)
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ osqa.fcgi/$1 [L]
   ```
7. Created a file named osqa.fcgi inside mysite.com:

   ```
   #!/home/username/python/bin/python  
   import os, sys

   sys.path.insert(0, "/home/your_username/")
   sys.path.append("/home/your_username/osqa")
   os.chdir("/home/your_username/osqa")

   os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "osqa.settings"

   from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
   runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
   ```
8. chmod +x osqa.fcgi

Now visiting the url mysite.com, simply gives me a 500 error.

Comment: @michael-hampton: Thanks for the formatting. I did try to format it, but I don't know, somehow it didn't work. Probably some browser or machine specific issue, so I posted the question anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. I am not sure, what exactly fixed it, but here is what all the changed I have made:

1. Modified .htaccess to replace osqa.fcgi with mysite.fcgi
2. Renamed the file osqa.fcgi to mysite.fcgi
3. At the top of mysite.fcgi, replaced the python path